# MapBasic | Objects Combine

Tags: mapbasic

Can anybody tell me how I can combine the geo objects of one relation to one single object? I reckon the Object Combine function is right one, but I have no idea how to specify the code...

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question. What do you meaa by "one relation"? Have you tried doing what you want to, thru the interface in MapInfo Pro with the MapBasic window open? This could produce some helpful MapBasic code

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [MapBasic Reference guide](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/10/MapBasicReference.pdf).  Pages 150-151 contain the syntax for the Objects Combine function.  You might also find the Objects Combine statement useful.  The syntax for that is found on pages 465-466.

You may also want to have a look at the Create Object statement which is on page 221.  Specifically, `Create Object As Union`.